# Does a string always be same sentencepiece tokenizer encode result?

Tags: nlp, encode, tokenize, sentencepiece

Will the tokenizer of `sentencepiece` always have the same encode result for the same string regardless of the context of the string?

For example:

```
sentence 1: abc bcde aa
sentence 2: nnnabc bcde zks
```

Will the overlap sub-string "abc bcde" get the same sentencepiece tokenizer encode result in both sentences?